# to reduce the sentence from A to C and from B to C

Tags: prepositions

I need to reduce the phrase "from A to C and from B to C".
Is this "from A and B to C" or "from both A and B to C"?

For example, if I need to reduce the following sentence:

> The Granger causality analysis demonstrated causalities **from** trust in executive power **to** political interest, and **from** trust in legislative powers **to** political interest.

What sentence has the same meaning?

> The Granger causality analysis demonstrated causalities **from** trust in executive **and** legislative powers **to** political interest, or
>
> The Granger causality analysis demonstrated causalities **from** **both** trust in executive **and** legislative powers **to** political interest.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence. What does it mean to say that there is a causality **from** A **to** B?  Does it mean that A caused B?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence two is better, because it is less ambiguous. "Both," in a way, establishes "trust in executive" and "legislative powers" as one unit, connecting them *both* to political interest. In sentence one, the connection between "trust in executive" and "political interest" is not as clear, because the former could be interpreted as distinct from "legislative powers," and therefore, "political interest."